# How to Check node existence in dell Boomi.

Tags: boomi

How to Check node existence in dell boomi, Like I have name element in source and sometime name is blank then I do not want to map that data on the target.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Decision Shape component for this purpose. 
From the configuration window in the First Value parameter Choose Profile Element -> select your profile and then your element(on the basis you want to add conditon) 
 From the configuration window in the Second Value parmeter Choose Static and blank value. Now the Decision shape will behave as per your requirement. If the element has a value it will go to True branch else it will go to False branch.
 Find more option and information:[Decision Shape example Boomi](http://help.boomi.com/atomsphere/GUID-622D5243-D439-4E88-9BEC-418F98396157.html)  
 I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping behavior you'll see is that the document that comes out of the map will not have any data profile fields that weren't set.

The destination data profile in the map can have a default value set to guard against the source data missing the desired field contents.

If I understand your question, if the name element/field is blank for a given mapped document, the document that emerges will "not map" that field, it will emerge with that mapped field missing.

Dell's doc on this doesn't cover your question, but does have some helpful detail: http://help.boomi.com/atomsphere/GUID-CA9E44A0-5621-46AE-8419-C334B374D7E3.html